# Problems importing package

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2, r-package

I'm developing a package and want to import all of the `dplyr` functions, so I added

`#' @import dplyr`

To my function and which generated a namespace which looks like this:

```
`# Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.1): do not edit by hand

export(process_text)
export(quick_match)
import(dplyr)`
```

But then when I load the package using `devtools::load_all()` I get an error:

> the dplyr functions are not availiable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to import it in your DESCRIPTION file. Something like this:

```
Package: <name>
Version: <version>
Date: <date>
Title: <title>
Author: <author>
Maintainer: <maintainer>
Depends:
    R (>= 2.13.0)
Imports:
    dplyr
Description: <description> 
License: GPL (>= 2)
```

Comment: Is dplyr installed correctly? Can you load the library independently of your package?

Comment: Yeah, if I use library(dplyr) within the function it works fine, but I'd prefer to load it through the namespace. 

Thanks for taking a stab at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you need the package to be listed in the Depends as well as the Imports section of the DESCRIPTION file. The following resolved the issue for me.

```
    Package: stringmatch
Title: Q-Gram filtering for approximate string matching
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
Description: An implementation of q-gram filtering for fast levenstein distance matching
Depends:R (>= 3.2.2),
  dplyr
Imports:
  dplyr,
```